# listview but no notifyDatasetChanged

Tags: android, listview, notifydatasetchanged

I have a `ListView` populated from a `ResourceCursorAdapter` (with `getView()` and `bindView()` methods) but there is no `notifyDatasetChanged()` option, only a `deferNotifyDatasetChanged()` (which doesn't do anything) one.

How can I mark the `ListView` to be updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there is no NotifyDatasetChanged option

[notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) is a method of the [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) class **not** of `ListView`

> How can I mark the listview to be updated

Try calling it on your `Adapter` so that it can be notified that the underlying data has been changed and update the `ListView`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean you populate a `ListView` from a `ResourceCursorAdapter`?

You need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `ResourceCursorAdapter` not on the `ListView`.

Comment: Thank you both for pointing out there error of my ways.  Put it down to a late night :(